# Move the selected row to the top or bottom of the excel table (excluding one column) using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have two VBA codes the first one moves the selected cell row in column (A, C, D, E and F) to the Top and other one moves the row cells to the bottom of the excel table.

For example if I select the cell in the C3 and run the macro the cells (A3, C3, D3,E3 and F3) in a row will move to the bottom of the table.

I have the following code which moves the entire row to the bottom:

```
Public Sub MoveToBottom()

    If Selection.Row <> 1 Then

        'move the whole row
        Selection.EntireRow.Cut
        Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert

    End If

End Sub
```

My Data looks like

[image: My Data looks like]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not really clear whether you want it to be moved to both the top and the bottom or whether you have some unmentioned criteria to decide whether it becomes the top or the bottom row

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I want 2 codes one moves the selected row to the top and one do the opposite moves the selected row toi the bottom. Moreover, the one I posted is example for moving the row to the bottom.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 thanx for the feedback I just edit the question to be clearer

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty quick and dirty but should do the trick for you.

It first checks that the selected row: has values, is not the header, and is not already the top/bottom row (depending on the function).

Then it inserts a row (for top only), copies the current row to where it belongs, and deletes the "old" row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveToTop()

    Dim rowCurrent As Long
    rowCurrent = Selection.row

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rows(rowCurrent)) >= 5 _
    And rowCurrent <> 1 And rowCurrent <> 2 Then
        Range("A2, C2:F2").Insert Shift:=xlDown

        Range("A" & rowCurrent).copy Destination:=Range("A2")
        Range("C" & rowCurrent & ":F" & rowCurrent).copy Destination:=Range("C2:F2")

        Range("A" & rowCurrent & ", " & "C" & rowCurrent & ":F" & rowCurrent).Delete
    End If

End Sub


Sub MoveToBottom()

    Dim rowCurrent As Long
    rowCurrent = Selection.row

    Dim rowLast As Long
    rowLast = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rows(rowCurrent)) >= 5 _
    And rowCurrent <> 1 And rowCurrent <> rowLast Then
        Range("A" & rowCurrent).copy Destination:=Range("A" & rowLast + 1)
        Range("C" & rowCurrent & ":F" & rowCurrent).copy Destination:=Range("C" & rowLast + 1 & ":F" & rowLast + 1)

        Range("A" & rowCurrent & ", " & "C" & rowCurrent & ":F" & rowCurrent).Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx a lot.. The Idea is to exclude the celles in column B (Column B is the priority and it shouldn't move). Your code moves the entire row. do you have an Idea how to exclude the column B.

Comment: I just realize that its doesn't work if the table is formatted as table. The problem is in the last line with the Delete one coz you cant delete the row in the table. Do have an Idea how to solve it?